# I keep getting this issue when trying to upload my plugin

Tags: wordpress

[image]Error: No license defined. Your plugin has no license declared. Please update your readme.txt with a GPLv2 (or later) compatible license.

Answer (score 1):

After research i find the solution of this issue it very much easy,
When we want to upload our plugin in wordpress directory,we need to should be create readme file nameed 'readme.txt'

**And one more important thing :**
The Plugin remade header consists of this information :

Before uploading plugin in WordPress directory, first should be read word press guideline carefully

https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/detailed-plugin-guidelines/

Goto this link :
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-org/how-your-readme-txt-works/#readmeheader-information